# UITableViewDelegate was not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

[image]

Here I used the UIsearchBar in "TO" and when user search something, I used the UITableView to show the search results. 
When user select a row from that results table, it will go to the detail page.
But In this situation, when user tap on the UITable View, It does not trigger the UITableView Delegate, didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Instead, dismiss the keyboard . Then user need to tap again on the table after dismissing the keyboard.
Therefore, user needs to tap twice whenever he wants to select a row from the result table. Could anyone help me for that problem?

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    if ([self.delegate     respondsToSelector:@selector(showCalloutRouteDestinationView:)])
        [self.delegate showCalloutRouteDestinationView:(int)searchBar.tag];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([self.delegate       respondsToSelector:@selector(showSearchFromResult:andTag:)])
            [self.delegate showSearchFromResult:searchText andTag:(int)searchBar.tag];

}
```

Here is my implementation for didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *location = self.searchByTextResults[indexPath.row];
    NSString *type = location[SERVER_CATEGORY];

    if  (indexPath.row == 0 && self.isTxtFrom){
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectAmenity:context:)])
            [self.delegate selectMyLocation:self.currentLocation];

        return;
    }else{
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didSelectDataForRoute:andType:context:)])
            [self.delegate didSelectDataForRoute:(self.isTxtFrom ?     self.searchByTextResults[indexPath.row - 1]:   self.searchByTextResults[indexPath.row]) andType:type   context:self.locationContext];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using swift 3?

Comment: add some relevant code in question.

Comment: @MianShahbazAkram No, I am using objective c

Comment: Did you set table view delegate to self?

Comment: @ovo yes, I have already set the uitableview delegate. That's why heightForRowAtIndexPath also being called. When I check, UITalbeview is always resign firstResponder. But I could not do it to become first responder.

Comment: once paste your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method also

Comment: @raki you could check in the question now :)

Comment: Is your class inherit from another class except UIViewController ?

Comment: @MianShahbazAkram Nope.

Comment: Do you allow row selection ?

Comment: [tableView setAllowsSelection:YES]

Comment: are you running any background threads during this ?

Comment: @MianShahbazAkram I have tried by adding [tableView setAllowsSelection:YES]. but it also did not work.

Comment: @DarkInnocence Nope.

Comment: are you using single selection ? Any gestures in the view controllers?

Comment: @DarkInnocence No I don't. Actually I have done that kind of similar feature in other view controller but I used UITextField delegate in that view controller. Now is using UISearchBar Delegate. Is it because of using UISearchBar?

Comment: I don't need to tap twice in this view controller. Here I used UITextField.![Valid XHTML](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-FBCTPV9IOTM/WVoGzmmE_sI/AAAAAAAADPc/PTazPglwgWkvPJKpyMb6GoqO3AUArR9awCL0BGAYYCw/h2048/eebfb46e-8d69-4eb4-ba61-bfdb37be7531).

Comment: @DarkInnocence Finally I found the gesture in my code. Now I already comment out these and working now. I think one of the seniors implemented that for some purpose. Thank you so much all.

Comment: have you set the searchBar delegate to self ?

Comment: great.. thought of some gesture messing with it already..